# Dropping rows from a dataframe programmatically; perplexing behavior

Tags: r

I've recently run into `R` behavior that perplexes me.  I'm hoping that someone can help me understand why the following is happening.

If I have a dataframe and I want to programmatically drop rows from that dataframe, I can use the following example code:

```
x <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10, 1), 
                num = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE))
y <- data.frame(id = c(2, 4, 6))

which(x$id %in% y$id)
x <- x[-which(x$id %in% y$id), ]
```

This yields exactly what I would expect:

```
> x
   id num
1   1   3
3   3   5
5   5   6
7   7   1
8   8   7
9   9   3
10 10   4
```

If I change `y` in the above code to be a number that **does not** appear in `x$id`,

```
x <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10, 1), 
                num = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE))

y <- data.frame(id = c(11))

which(x$id %in% y$id)
x <- x[-which(x$id %in% y$id), ]
```

I would have expected **no** rows to be removed from `x`, but instead, `x` is empty:

```
> x
[1] id  num
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can someone please explain why this happens?  I would have expected to get my original `x` dataframe because there were no values of `x$id` in `y$id`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do not need to use `which` with `%in%`, it returns boolean values. So you could do something like `!(x$id %in% y$id)`. That should work.

Comment: I know, but I've always felt more comfortable dropping rows based upon row index rather than a vector of boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a match then the result of `which()` is an empty vector, so you're asking for no rows = empty data frame. Note that negation has no effect in that case since there is nothing to negate.

To be perfectly clear, the `-` sign in the subsetting has no special meaning, it simply negates the integers you pass. If you don't pass anything, there it nothing to negate.

Comment: I would have thought that if the `which()` statement returned an empty vector (i.e., 0 rows), then negating the empty vector (dropping 0 rows from `x`) would have been the result.  It seems though, that my logic is the opposite of `R`'s logic.

Comment: You're simply applying unary minus `-` to integers, so zero-length integer vector `integer()` is exactly the same as its negation `-integer()` - it is still just a zero-length vector `integer()`. So you're asking R to subset with an empty index which by any logic I can think of should result in an empty data frame. Maybe you're thinking of boolean negation `!` and not unary minus `-`?